# How do I align vertically centered a Spinner and a TextView

Tags: android

I have a Spinner and a TextView in my LinearLayour.

I am trying to align the Spinner and a TextView vertically so that the center of both in on the same line:

[image]

This is my XML for that element:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dropdownlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ok1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/white_box"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normale" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Tried this code as well, same result:

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/dropdownlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ok1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner1"
        android:background="@drawable/white_box"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normale" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Several solutions. Play with Gravity and Layout_gravity. As i can see you have used gravity for the linearlayout, layout_gravity for the spinner and TextView and gravity on top of that. Else try using Relative layout with CenterInParent

Comment: @Yume117 thanks Youme117 but believe me I have tried a lot!! :-)

Comment: Is the paddingRight on the textview messing with the centering?

Comment: @wyoskibum mmm... I do not know... is that possible? Because I need some padding to make the box not too small

Comment: Shouldn't you be using layout_gravity for the linear layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in Relative Layout like this

```
[<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/dropdownlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
         android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ok1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/white_box"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner1"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normale" />
</RelativeLayout>]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Brontok, but when i run it on a real device I get the same result as before :-( thanks anyway

Comment: Hmmm Can you please specify which device you are using

Comment: Galaxy ACE. But I don't think the issue is with the phone.I edited the code, using your suggestion, please have a look.

Answer (score 3):

Well note that you can't use RelativeLayout with Gravity or Layout_gravity

an example of how i do things. This works perfectly (it's at the right of a list view cell centerred verticaly)

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="4dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/annuaire_distance_etablissement"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow_img"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/clr_main_green"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow_img"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icone_fleche" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for the remarks Yume117. Followed your suggestion but without success: same result

Comment: It's a layout/positionning issu so your only solution is to try things out (LinearLayout/relativelayout, use gravity with linear, use layout_centerVertical/centerInParent with Relative Layout) :/ edit : Did you try to make your spinner height : Match_parent ? ====> If i were in that situation i would use lineralayout horizontal and have both spinner and textview have weight=50 and height = 48dp and width = matchparent so that they have the same size and add some padding to the linearlayout to make it look better ...

Comment: I was trying to align a TextView and a Spinner, and adding `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to the TextView did the trick. This was with a RelativeLayout.

Comment: just replace any component by your spinner

Answer (score 2):

You can simple wrap the `Spinner` and `TextView` inside a `LinearLayout` like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Remove the row

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner1"
```

and if you want you can make relative the `LinearLayout` (adding the layout_below, layout_above, etc)

Then, inside both `TextView` and `Spinner` add:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

Comment: thank you Joseph82 I have tried your solution with no better luck: same result...:-(((

Comment: I'm sorry @Lisa, I have not other ideas. :(

Answer (score 1):

You should stick to the linear layout and try the following on the TextView:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

and then in your TextView you should change

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

into

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```